# Image upload issue with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm stuck with an issue updating images. I've created image upload which works fine but when I try to update an entry with other details which already has an image, it throws an error. Is there a way we can skip the image upload check altogether and the entry updates with or without the image?

**View:**

````php
    <!-- begin .app -->
    <div class="app">
        <!-- begin .app-wrap -->
        <div class="app-wrap">
            <!-- begin .app-heading -->
        <?php require_once("header.php"); ?>
          <!-- END:  .app-heading -->

          <!-- begin .app-container -->
          <div class="app-container">
        <?php require_once("sidebar.php"); ?>
            <!-- begin .app-side -->

            <!-- END: .app-side -->

            <!-- begin .app-main -->
            <div class="app-main">
              <!-- begin .main-heading -->
              <header class="main-heading shadow-2dp">
                <!-- begin dashhead -->
                <div class="dashhead bg-white">
                  <div class="dashhead-titles">

                    <h3 class="dashhead-title">Add Mick Chocolate</h3>
                  </div>

                  <div class="dashhead-toolbar">
                    <div class="dashhead-toolbar-item">
                      <a href="">Chocolate</a>
                      / Home / Add Mick Chocolate
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END: dashhead -->
              </header>
              <!-- END: .main-heading -->
              <!-- begin .main-content -->
              <div class="main-content bg-clouds">

                <!-- begin .container-fluid -->
                <div class="container-fluid p-t-15">
                  <div class="box">
                    <header class="bg-alizarin text-white">
                      <h4>Input</h4>
                    </header>
                    <div class="box-body collapse in">

                    <?php

                        echo form_open_multipart('Admin/admin_add_image');

                    ?> 

                      <form class="form-horizontal" action = "" method ="post">
                     <hr class="b-s-dashed">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="text1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" id="text1" name="chocolate_name" pattern="^[A-Za-z -]+$" required >
                          </div>
                        </div><br><br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="text2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" id="text2" name="chocolate_price" pattern="^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$" required >
                          </div>
                        </div><br><br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="text3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload Image</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="file" id="text3" name="file_to_upload" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg">
                          </div>
                        </div><br><br>
                                <button type="submit" name="btn_add" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
                      </form>
                      </div>
                      <!-- END: .container-fluid -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- END: .main-content -->

                    <!-- begin .main-footer -->
                    <footer class="main-footer bg-white p-a-5">

                    </footer>
                    <!-- END: .main-footer -->

                  </div>
                  <!-- END: .app-main -->
                </div>
                <!-- END: .app-container -->

                <!-- begin .app-footer -->
               <?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>
                <!-- END: .app-footer -->

              </div>
              <!-- END: .app-wrap -->
            </div>
            <!-- END: .app -->

**Model**

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AdminModel extends CI_Model {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function admin_register_done()
    {
        $admin_name=$this->input->post('admin_name');
        $admin_email=$this->input->post('admin_email');
        $admin_mobileno=$this->input->post('admin_mobileno');
        $admin_username=$this->input->post('admin_username');
        $admin_password=$this->input->post('admin_password');
        $data=array(
            'admin_name'=>$admin_name,
            'admin_email'=>$admin_email,
            'admin_mobileno'=>$admin_mobileno,
            'admin_username'=>$admin_username,
            'admin_password'=>$admin_password
        );
        $this->db->insert('tbl_admin_registration',$data);
    }
    public function admin_login_done()
    {
        $admin_username=$this->input->post('admin_username');
        $admin_password=$this->input->post('admin_password');
        $this->db->select('admin_username','admin_password');
        $this->db->from('tbl_admin_registration');
        $this->db->where('admin_username',$admin_username);
        $this->db->where("admin_password",$admin_password);
        return $query=$this->db->get();
    }
    public function admin_add_image_done($image)
    {
        $image_info = $this->upload->data();
        $chocolate_name=$this->input->post('chocolate_name');
        $chocolate_price=$this->input->post('chocolate_price');
        $data=array(
            'image_name'=>'http://candymart.co.in/Admin/uploads/'.$image_info['file_name'],
            'chocolate_name'=>$chocolate_name,
            'chocolate_price'=>$chocolate_price 
        );
        $this->db->insert('tbl_admin_chocolate',$data);
    }
        public function admin_add_image_done1()
    {

        $chocolate_name=$this->input->post('chocolate_name');
        $chocolate_price=$this->input->post('chocolate_price');
        $data=array(
            'chocolate_name'=>$chocolate_name,
            'chocolate_price'=>$chocolate_price 
        );
        $this->db->insert('tbl_admin_chocolate',$data);
    }
    public function admin_add_madhurimage_done()
    {
        $image_info = $this->upload->data();
        $chocolate_name=$this->input->post('chocolate_name');
        $chocolate_price=$this->input->post('chocolate_price');
        $data=array(
            'image_name'=>$image_info['file_name'],
            'chocolate_name'=>$chocolate_name,
            'chocolate_price'=>$chocolate_price 
        );
        $this->db->insert('tbl_admin_madhurchocolate',$data);
    }
    public function admin_add_crystalimage_done()
    {
        $image_info = $this->upload->data();
        $chocolate_name=$this->input->post('chocolate_name');
        $chocolate_price=$this->input->post('chocolate_price');
        $data=array(
            'image_name'=>$image_info['file_name'],
            'chocolate_name'=>$chocolate_name,
            'chocolate_price'=>$chocolate_price 
        );
        $this->db->insert('tbl_admin_crystalchocolate',$data);
    }
    public function admin_add_candyimage_done()
    {
        $image_info = $this->upload->data();
        $chocolate_name=$this->input->post('chocolate_name');
        $chocolate_price=$this->input->post('chocolate_price');
        $data=array(
            'image_name'=>$image_info['file_name'],
            'chocolate_name'=>$chocolate_name,
            'chocolate_price'=>$chocolate_price 
        );
        $this->db->insert('tbl_admin_candychocolate',$data);
    }

        public function admin_display_image_done()
    {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_admin_chocolate');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
        public function admin_display_madhurimage_done()
    {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_admin_madhurchocolate');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
        public function admin_display_crystalimage_done()
    {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_admin_crystalchocolate');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
       public function admin_display_candyimage_done()
    {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_admin_candychocolate');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    public function admin_delete_image_done($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('tbl_admin_chocolate.id',$id);
        return $this->db->delete('tbl_admin_chocolate');

    }
    public function admin_delete_madhurimage_done($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('tbl_admin_madhurchocolate.id',$id);
        return $this->db->delete('tbl_admin_madhurchocolate');

    }
    public function admin_delete_crystalimage_done($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('tbl_admin_crystalchocolate.id',$id);
        return $this->db->delete('tbl_admin_crystalchocolate');

    }
        public function admin_delete_candyimage_done($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('tbl_admin_candychocolate.id',$id);
        return $this->db->delete('tbl_admin_candychocolate');

    }
    public function admin_edit_chocolate_done($id)
    {
       $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_admin_chocolate',array('id'=>$id));
       return $query->row_array();
    }
    public function admin_edit_madhurchocolate_done($id)
    {
       $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_admin_madhurchocolate',array('id'=>$id));
       return $query->row_array();
    }
    public function admin_edit_crystalchocolate_done($id)
    {
       $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_admin_crystalchocolate',array('id'=>$id));
       return $query->row_array();
    }
    public function admin_edit_candychocolate_done($id)
    {
       $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_admin_candychocolate',array('id'=>$id));
       return $query->row_array();
    }
    public function admin_update_chocolate_done($id)
    {
        $image_info = $this->upload->data();
        $chocolate_name=$this->input->post('chocolate_name');
        $chocolate_price=$this->input->post('chocolate_price');


        $data=array(
            'image_name'=>'http://candymart.co.in/Admin/uploads/'.$image_info['file_name'],
            'chocolate_name'=>$chocolate_name,
            'chocolate_price'=>$chocolate_price
        );
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where('tbl_admin_chocolate.id',$id);
        return $this->db->update('tbl_admin_chocolate',$data);
    }
        public function admin_update_madhurchocolate_done($id)
    {
        $image_info = $this->upload->data();
        $chocolate_name=$this->input->post('chocolate_name');
        $chocolate_price=$this->input->post('chocolate_price');


        $data=array(
            'image_name'=>$image_info['file_name'],
            'chocolate_name'=>$chocolate_name,
            'chocolate_price'=>$chocolate_price
        );
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where('tbl_admin_madhurchocolate.id',$id);
        return $this->db->update('tbl_admin_madhurchocolate',$data);
    }
        public function admin_update_crystalchocolate_done($id)
    {
        $image_info = $this->upload->data();
        $chocolate_name=$this->input->post('chocolate_name');
        $chocolate_price=$this->input->post('chocolate_price');


        $data=array(
            'image_name'=>$image_info['file_name'],
            'chocolate_name'=>$chocolate_name,
            'chocolate_price'=>$chocolate_price
        );
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where('tbl_admin_crystalchocolate.id',$id);
        return $this->db->update('tbl_admin_crystalchocolate',$data);
    }
        public function admin_update_candychocolate_done($id)
    {
        $image_info = $this->upload->data();
        $chocolate_name=$this->input->post('chocolate_name');
        $chocolate_price=$this->input->post('chocolate_price');


        $data=array(
            'image_name'=>$image_info['file_name'],
            'chocolate_name'=>$chocolate_name,
            'chocolate_price'=>$chocolate_price
        );
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where('tbl_admin_candychocolate.id',$id);
        return $this->db->update('tbl_admin_candychocolate',$data);
    }
}
````

**Controller**

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('manisha_admin');
    }
    public function admin_register()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin_register');
    }
    public function admin_register_data()
    {

        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $this->AdminModel->admin_register_done();
        $this->load->view('admin_login');
    }
    public function admin_login()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin_login');
    }
    public function admin_login_data()
    {

        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $this->AdminModel->admin_login_done();
        $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_image_done(); 
        $this->load->view('add_image',$data);
    }
    public function admin_add_image()
    {
         $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; 
         //$config['max_size']      = 100; 
         //$config['max_width']     = 1024; 
         //$config['max_height']    = 768;  
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_to_upload')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            //$image = 'http://candymart.co.in/Admin/uploads/1.JPG';
            $this->load->view('add_image');
         }

         else { 
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            //$image = $_FILES['file_to_upload']['name'];
            $this->load->view('Upload_success', $data); 
            $this->load->model('AdminModel');
            $this->AdminModel->admin_add_image_done();

         } 
    }
    public function admin_add_madhurimage()
    {
         $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; 
         //$config['max_size']      = 100; 
         //$config['max_width']     = 1024; 
         //$config['max_height']    = 768;  
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_to_upload')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->load->view('add_madhurimage', $error); 
         }

         else { 
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
            $this->load->view('Upload_success', $data); 
            $this->load->model('AdminModel');
            $this->AdminModel->admin_add_madhurimage_done();
         } 
    }
        public function admin_add_crystalimage()
    {
         $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; 
         //$config['max_size']      = 100; 
         //$config['max_width']     = 1024; 
         //$config['max_height']    = 768;  
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_to_upload')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->load->view('add_crystalimage', $error); 
         }

         else { 
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
            $this->load->view('Upload_success', $data); 
            $this->load->model('AdminModel');
            $this->AdminModel->admin_add_crystalimage_done();
         } 
    }
        public function admin_add_candyimage()
    {
         $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; 
         //$config['max_size']      = 100; 
         //$config['max_width']     = 1024; 
         //$config['max_height']    = 768;  
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_to_upload')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->load->view('add_candyimage', $error); 
         }

         else { 
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
            $this->load->view('Upload_success', $data); 
            $this->load->model('AdminModel');
            $this->AdminModel->admin_add_candyimage_done();
         } 
    }
    public function admin_edit_image()
    {
         $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
         //$config['max_size']      = 100; 
         //$config['max_width']     = 1024; 
         //$config['max_height']    = 768;  
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_to_upload')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->load->view('edit_chocolate', $error); 
         }

         else { 
            $id = $this->input->post('hidden_id1');
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
            //$this->load->view('Upload_success',$data); 
            $this->load->model('AdminModel');
            $this->AdminModel->admin_update_chocolate_done($id);
            $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_image_done(); 
            $this->load->view('display_image',$data);
         } 
    }
    public function admin_edit_madhurimage()
    {
         $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; 
         //$config['max_size']      = 100; 
         //$config['max_width']     = 1024; 
         //$config['max_height']    = 768;  
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_to_upload')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->load->view('edit_madhurchocolate', $error); 
         }

         else { 
            $id = $this->input->post('hidden_id2');
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
            //$this->load->view('Upload_success',$data); 
            $this->load->model('AdminModel');
            $this->AdminModel->admin_update_madhurchocolate_done($id);
            $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_madhurimage_done(); 
            $this->load->view('display_madhurimage',$data);
         } 
    }
    public function admin_edit_crystalimage()
    {
         $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; 
         //$config['max_size']      = 100; 
         //$config['max_width']     = 1024; 
         //$config['max_height']    = 768;  
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_to_upload')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->load->view('edit_crystalchocolate', $error); 
         }

         else { 
            $id = $this->input->post('hidden_id3');
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
            //$this->load->view('Upload_success',$data); 
            $this->load->model('AdminModel');
            $this->AdminModel->admin_update_crystalchocolate_done($id);
            $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_crystalimage_done(); 
            $this->load->view('display_crystalimage',$data);

         } 
    }
    public function admin_edit_candyimage()
    {
         $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; 
         //$config['max_size']      = 100; 
         //$config['max_width']     = 1024; 
         //$config['max_height']    = 768;  
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_to_upload')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->load->view('edit_candychocolate', $error); 
         }

         else { 
            $id = $this->input->post('hidden_id4');
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
            //$this->load->view('Upload_success',$data); 
            $this->load->model('AdminModel');
            $this->AdminModel->admin_update_candychocolate_done($id);
            $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_candyimage_done(); 
            $this->load->view('display_candyimage',$data);
         } 
    }
    public function admin_display_image()
    {
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_image_done(); 
        $this->load->view('display_image',$data);
    }
    public function admin_display_madhurimage()
    {
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_madhurimage_done(); 
        $this->load->view('display_madhurimage',$data);
    }
    public function admin_display_crystalimage()
    {
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_crystalimage_done(); 
        $this->load->view('display_crystalimage',$data);
    }
    public function admin_display_candyimage()
    {
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_candyimage_done(); 
        $this->load->view('display_candyimage',$data);
    }

    public function admin_delete_image()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $this->AdminModel->admin_delete_image_done($id);
        $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_image_done(); 
        $this->load->view('display_image',$data);
    }
        public function admin_delete_madhurimage()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $this->AdminModel->admin_delete_madhurimage_done($id);
        $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_madhurimage_done(); 
        $this->load->view('display_madhurimage',$data);

    }
            public function admin_delete_crystalimage()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $this->AdminModel->admin_delete_crystalimage_done($id);
        $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_crystalimage_done(); 
        $this->load->view('display_crystalimage',$data);

    }
            public function admin_delete_candyimage()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $this->AdminModel->admin_delete_candyimage_done($id);
        $data['sub'] = $this->AdminModel->admin_display_candyimage_done(); 
        $this->load->view('display_candyimage',$data);
    }
    public function admin_edit_chocolate()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $data['user1']=$this->AdminModel->admin_edit_chocolate_done($id);
        $this->load->view('edit_chocolate',$data);

    }
        public function admin_edit_madhurchocolate()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $data['user2']=$this->AdminModel->admin_edit_madhurchocolate_done($id);
        $this->load->view('edit_madhurchocolate',$data);

    }
        public function admin_edit_crystalchocolate()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $data['user3']=$this->AdminModel->admin_edit_crystalchocolate_done($id);
        $this->load->view('edit_crystalchocolate',$data);

    }
        public function admin_edit_candychocolate()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $data['user4']=$this->AdminModel->admin_edit_candychocolate_done($id);
        $this->load->view('edit_candychocolate',$data);

    }
        public function admin_update_chocolate()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('hidden_id1');
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $this->AdminModel->admin_update_chocolate_done($id);
    }
        public function admin_update_madhurchocolate()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('hidden_id2');
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $this->AdminModel->admin_update_madhurchocolate_done($id);

    }
        public function admin_update_crystalchocolate()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('hidden_id3');
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $this->AdminModel->admin_update_crystalchocolate_done($id);

    }
        public function admin_update_candychocolate()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('hidden_id4');
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $this->AdminModel->admin_update_candychocolate_done($id);

    }
        public function admin_logout()
    {
        $user_data = $this->session->all_userdata();
        foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 'session_id' && $key != 'ip_address' && $key != 'user_agent' && $key != 'last_activity') {
                $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
            }
        }
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('Admin/index');
     }

}
```

Comment: In the view you are using two `<form>` tags.

Comment: And now what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
<?php
   ....
   if($_FILES["file_name"]["name"] != "") {
       //file uploading code
   }
   ....
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the controller while updating

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_to_upload']['name'])){
   //Image uploading...
}
//Updating other data...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed you have write form tag 2 time. check the view

```
<?php
echo form_open_multipart('Admin/admin_add_image');
?> 
<form class="form-horizontal" action = "" method ="post">
```

First remove one of them and try to upload image again.

Answer (score 0):

Your view file HTML form should have enctype attribute to upload file.

`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 </form>`

Answer (score 0):

When update all detail that time check in this condition in controller.

```
if (!empty($_FILES['chooseFileImage']['tmp_name'])) {
  // if true this condition you can update image
} else {
  // if false then not update image filed
}
```